# react useContext implementation with hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this definition

```
  export interface user{
    email:string
    name:string
    last_name:string
  }  

  export type UserType= {
    user: user;
    setUser:(user:user) => void;
  }

const [user,setUser] = useState <user> ({
    email:"",
    name:"",
    last_name:"",
   
})

export const  UserContext = createContext <UserType>({user,setUser});
```

Then in App.tsx

```
    function App() {
 const [user,setUser] = useState <usuario> ({
        email:"",
        name:"",
        last_name:"",
        
 })
    
    return 
      (
  <UserContext.Provider  value={ {user,setUser} } >
         <Home/> 
        <About/>
      </UserContext.Provider>
      )
    }
    export default App
```

At home there is the problem because I need to set the email so:

```
export const Home= () => {
    const {user,setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
    /*....... Some code*/

    setUser((state) => ({ ...state, email: email.current }))

}
```

whith the sentence setUser((state) => ({ ...state, email: email.current }))

> An argument of type "(state: any) => any" cannot be assigned to a
> parameter of type "user".   The type "(state: any) => any" is missing
> the following properties of the type "user": email, name and
> last_name.

and it does not work with this: setUser((state:user) => ({ ...state, email: email.current }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current definition of `setUser` ignores the ability to pass a function. You'll need to define the `setUser` type to be identical to the one produces from `useState`:

```
import { SetStateAction, Dispatch } from 'react';

export interface UserType {
  user: User;
  setUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<User>>;
}
```